# Know in `activate` if the navigation was due to clicking on the nav-bar

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to get 3 different routing "styles" in my application.  I need to identify these in each view-model's `activate` method:

1. User clicks a button or link in my app that causes my app to call `this.router.navigate()`

   - This one is easy because I always put a parameter into the URL, so in the target View-Model, I have that param in my `activate` method.
2. The users presses the back or forward buttons or loads the application for the first time.

   - I can also get this by using the `this.router.isExplicitNavigation` variable or checking if my state is uninitalized.
3. The user clicks on one of the views displayed in the `nav-bar` (setup in the `app.ts` `configureRouter` method).

   - Unfortunately I cannot find a way to distinguish this one from when the user presses the back and forward buttons on the browser.

**So here is my question, is there a way to know when a view-model's `activate` method has been called because a user selected a `nav-bar` route?**

Comment: I don't know if there's an aurelia way to achieve what you want, but you could simplify things by using querystrings, such as &ref=navbar. So, you would know that the user came from a navbar link. Facebook does that all the time...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want distinguish between 1. and 3. In `activate()`, you receive all routing parameters (as the method's first argument), both:

- from the route-template, such as `/myRoute/:myparam`
- from the query string

So I'd suggest to put a query parameter for the menu bar, which parameter you can read in `activate()`. For example:

- let's say your route `/myRoute`
- from the button, simply navigate to `/myRoute`
- from the navbar, navigate to `/myRoute?from=navbar`

You might know this, but you have multiple options to navigate from code:

- `router.navigate('compose your route manually')`
- `router.navigateToRoute('route's name', parameters)`
- in template, using `<a route-href="route: 'myRoute'; params.bind={...}" >`

Your code:

```
//button
router.navigateToRoute('my-route');

//navbar
router.navigateToRoute('my-route', {from: 'navbar'});

//destination view-model
activate(params: Object): void {
    if (params.from === 'navbar')
        //routed from the navbar
    else
        //routed from a button
}
```